# jenkins run pywinauto start not use

Tags: jenkins, pywinauto

i run my code on vscode ide or use cmd will be fine, but when i use jenkins run windows batch cmd will be fail (app start no use) , my jenkins also run on admin

```
    C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Agent_Automation>python test_enf_ins_gui.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 436, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 87, in find_element
    raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'class_name': 'MsiDialogCloseClass', 'backend': 'uia', 'visible_only': False}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_enf_ins_gui.py", line 5, in <module>
    r'C:\Users\txone\Downloads\Install.exe').connect(class_name="MsiDialogCloseClass",timeout=20)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 994, in connect
    *(), **kwargs
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 458, in wait_until_passes
    raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError
```

Comment: Also you may need `Applcation(backend="uia")` for some modern apps. Default "win32" backend uses old Win32 API for getting text data and hierarchy. I guess you use "win32" backend because class_name is used. With "uia" it is usually control_type. But "win32" works faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you run Jenkins agent as a service, Windows will not give you access to create/control any GUI. You have to start Jenkins agent under normal user, not as a service (maybe using Windows scheduler). Many hints are collected in the [Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html). There are many things how to handle RDP or VNC desktop. Please read carefully.

P.S. Also PsExec may hang under Jenkins/Java (known issue, probably not your case), but you can use open-source analogue PAExec with similar options if you need it one day.